# I want to know about print type explicitly

Tags: c

Print type like %s, %d, %x, %p, ...
I understand these things roughly. But when I have to choose one of these,  I can't pick similar two of these. For example, when I try to print address of variable, I can have %p or %08X, they will be certainly different in special case. I want to know definition of these print type in order to make reasonable decision. I couldn't find any resource in C standard.

Comment: [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: They're all explicitly defined in the standard. Check **7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions**. Is there something specific you're asking?

Comment: @Carl Norum Nope, that is what i wanted. thx.

Comment: You can also read the `printf()` man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must a format specifier that matches the type of the value you are printing.

`%p` expects a `void *`.

`%x` expects an `unsigned int`.

`%lx` expects an `unsigned long`.

This is documented in `man 3 printf`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   const char *s = "foo";
   printf("%p\n", s);
   printf("%s\n", PRIxPTR);
   printf("%#" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)s);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 a.c -o a && a
0x5b72da1774
lx
0x5b72da1774
```

`PRIxPTR` will be something like `x`. In my case, it's `lx` because a pointer is the same size as an `unsigned long`.

Comment: `man 3 printf` documents Unix’s specification for `printf`, not the C standard’s specification and should not be given as a reference in a C question without cautioning the reader that it is not portable for C generally.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Feel free to edit in a better link